# Finding time bound path to point in 2D space

Tags: math, vector, physics, space, path-finding

I am trying to do flight planning in 3D space, but I actually want to figure out doing it in 2D space first. I have:

- an object with a known current position and known current velocity vector
- a desired point in space
- a desired velocity vector
- a desired time

I want to plan a route for the object to take to reach the desired point at the desired time travelling at the desired vector, and taking into account the objects starting vector.

I'm at a bit of a loss on how to achieve this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: So you want to arrive at a specific point with a specific final velocity in a specific amount of time? It seems like this problem is underconstrained and there are too many possible solutions. For example, I could instantaneously switch my initial velocity vector to point toward the destination, though this could result in a *very* high acceleration. Or I could take some crazy, looping path very quickly at the start of the journey as long as I make sure I arrive at the destination properly.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by eigenchris in a comment, this problem has many possible solutions, so I will propose a method that gives sensible results and allows for flexible customization, depending on the desired properties of your path.

It's easier to split the problem into two parts, first find a path in 2D and then compute the distance along it and solve the problem of matching the velocity and acceleration to the distance as a 1D (plus time) problem.

For the path, [Cubic Bézier curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Constructing_B.C3.A9zier_curves) seem ideally suited to the problem. A [cubic Bézier curve](http://www.ibiblio.org/e-notes/Splines/bezier.html) is defined by 4 control points P0, P1, P2 and P3.

P0 and P3 are the start and end points of the curve. P1 and P2 are control points that are used for specifying the tangent of the curve at the start and end points (defined by the lines P0-P1 and P2-P3 respectively). If you fly along the curve, those are the directions you are moving at the start and end points.

Here is an [interactive demo](http://lib.ivank.net/?p=demos&d=bezier) to get a feel for how the positioning of the control points influences the curve (the cubic Bézier is the blue curve on the right with 4 control points).

To define a flight path using a Bézier curve:

- Set P0 to the start point of your flight path
- Set P3 to the end point
- Set P1 to a point in the direction of the starting velocity vector from P0
- Set P2 to a point in the opposite direction to the ending velocity vector from P3

[image]

Note that the distances from P0 to P1 and from P2 to P3 do not represent the magnitude of the starting and ending velocities. Rather, they specify the tightness of the turn at the start and end of the curve to align the curve with the start and end tangents. Pull the control points in close for a tight turn, push them further out for a wider turn. However if you want to you can make the turn wider the larger the desired velocity vector is, to be more physically realistic.

If you don't want to be turning the whole time, you can segment the path into several Bézier curves, or a Bézier curve then a straight line then a Bézier curve, and make the tangents match up where the different segments meet. For example you might want to take a curved path at the start of the flight path, then follow a straight line for most of the way, the follow a curved path at the end to line up with the desired final direction vector. This gives you total control over your flight path.

The solution generalizes easily to 3 dimensions.

Now that you have a path, you need to figure out how to accelerate and decelerate along the curve to arrive at the destination at the right time and the right speed. First, calculate the distance along the curve:

[Arc Length of Bézier Curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12186/arc-length-of-b%C3%A9zier-curves)

If you know the start time, the end time and the start and end speeds (magnitude of start and end velocity vectors), you can work out how far along the curve you would have flown between the start and end times, assuming you linearly accelerate from the starting speed to the ending speed over the course of the journey (distance is the area under the line):

[image]

Since this area will most likely be different to the computed distance along the Bézier Curve, you need to create a segmented function that has the desired area under the line between the start and end times. The image shows two such functions to handle the cases where the distance traveled is greater than desired, and the area is decreased by slowing down then travelling at constant speed then speeding up, and vice versa. The examples show instantaneous changes in acceleration, but not in speed. You can choose any function you like as long as the start and end speeds at the start and end times match the desired values and the area under the function is equal to the distance along the path.

Comment: Apparently I'm not reputed enough to vote this up, but this is a very detailed answer. Thank you! I'm going through it step by step now.